# Remove element from Angular Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a angular array of **5 elements**.

```
$scope.details;
```

and `$scope.details` have these following elements `[id, name, points]`.

and now using loop I have added a new element to this `$scope.details` for every element.

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.details.length; i++){
  $scope.details[i].check = 'f';
}
```

So, the elements are `[id, name, points, check]`;

Now, after performing the logic i need to remove the check from all 5 elements of `$scope.details`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your code aren't adding `check` property to each element in `details` Array. To do it update code to:

```
for(var i=0; i<$scope.details.length; i++){
  $scope.details[i].check = 'f';
}
```

**To remove** check element from each item use for loop and delete:

```
for(var i=0; i<$scope.details.length, i++){
  delete $scope.details[i].check
}
```

In your code snippet you adding `check` property to `$scope.details`, so you can remove it **without for loop**:

```
delete $scope.details.check
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) like so:

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.details.length;i++){
  delete $scope.details[i].check;
}
```

Or using slightly newer API

```
$scope.details.forEach(function(item){
  delete item.check;
}
```

Comment: I need to only delete the `check ` from the array. So, that it would be again like `[id, name,points]`

Answer (score 0):

We can pass index / id and write delete function in service js file as below:

```
RemoveFromCart(indexP){
    this.items.splice(indexP, 1);   
  }
```